# Bash Script for Dumping the Android Partition is not consistent

Tags: command-line, partitioning, bash, scripts, android

I really need your suggestion about my current problem.  I am trying to dump the whole partitions on the Android with netcat.  I have created 4 bash scripts for automation process. So, I only need to execute the RunThis1.sh that actually executes script1.sh, script2.sh and script3.sh. I use screen to run those 3 scripts for running in the 3 different terminal. The 3 scripts should be running consecutively, therefore should be an time interval between those 3 scripts to be executed.
The problem is and I don't know why the problem is persists, the output is not consistent. At first, I succeed to get the dd images from it. But currently, it was failed. Either I got zero size file or it was text file. Instead the dd image.

This is the ***RunThis1.sh:***

```
#!/bin/bash
function GetPartitionName () {
#init number of line
sum=0
PartNameArray=""
while IFS=$' ' read -r column1 column2 column3 column4 ; do
    temp=${column4}
    if [ -n $temp ]; 
    then
        PartNameArray[$sum]=$temp;
        sum=$((sum+1));
    fi                      
done < ProcPart.txt
sum=$((sum-1));
}

#set working folder path, change to machine's specific path
 path="/home/android/Work/"

 #set partition list source file name
 partList="ProcPart.txt"

 #Lock files to maintain sequences
 lock1=$path"file1.lock"
 lock2=$path"file2.lock"
 lock3=$path"file3.lock"

#initialize no of partition
 sum=0
 i=1

#Starting port, the next port is increment by 2
 PortStart=8888

#initialize files and folder
 find $path -name 'screenlog*' -delete
 find $path"partitions/" -name '*' -delete
 mkdir -p $path/partitions || exit 1

#run the get partition name function
 if (test -f "$partList") then GetPartitionName
else
    echo "Partition list file $partList not found!"
    echo "script aborted."
    exit
fi

#start iteration
for (( c=0; c<"$sum"; c++ ))
do  
touch "$lock1"; screen -d -m -L -S "Screen PID for script #1"     ./script1.sh "$PortStart";rm -f "$lock1";
echo "==========================================================="  
echo "Establish forward socket connection at tcp port# $PortStart"
echo ". <done>"
if !(test -f "$lock1"); then                
    DevBlockPath="/dev/block/${PartNameArray[$c]}"
    echo "Open Remote Shell and send $DevBlockPath to NC Server at port# $PortStart"
    echo "Processing partition no $i out of $sum"   
    touch "$lock2"; screen -d -m -L -S "Screen PID for script #2" ./script2.sh "$PortStart $DevBlockPath"; 
    echo "."
    echo ".. <done>"
fi
if (test -f "$lock2") then
    sleep 5
    FileName=$path"partitions/${PartNameArray[$c]}.dd"      
    echo "Transfer data from Remote NC server port# $PortStart to localfile $FileName"  
    rm -f "$lock2"; touch "$lock3"; screen -d -m -L -S "Screen PID for script #3" ./script3.sh "$PortStart $FileName"; rm -f "$lock3";
    echo "."
    echo ".."
    echo "... <done>"   
fi
i=$((i+1));
PortStart=$((PortStart+2));
done
echo ===========================================================
```

***Script1.sh:***

```
#!/bin/bash
# first script
function script1 {
echo script1 port=$1
adb forward tcp:"$1" tcp:"$1"
}

script1 $1
```

***Script2.sh:***

```
#!/bin/bash
# second script
function script2 {
echo path=$2
strcommand="dd if=$2 | /dev/examiner/nc -l -p $1"
echo command=$strcommand
adb shell "$strcommand"
}

script2 $1 $2
```

***Script3.sh:***

```
#!/bin/bash
# third script
function script3 {
echo port=$1
echo filename=$2
#dump random words from openned NC ports to mtdbackup.dd
nc 127.0.0.1 $1 > "$2";
echo " dump randomFile $2 from NC has completed";
exit;
}
function quit {
exit
}
```

Any advice and suggestion are more than welcome and will be appriciated.

Cheers

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the point of having your scripts use functions? That just adds complexity for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it way too hard. This code is set to run the three commands *concurrently*, and you're having to work with locks and such to force it to run *consecutively*. I don't think you need `screen` at all here.

Try replacing the `screen` commands with the command they call. That is, replace

```
screen -d -m -L -S "Screen PID for script #1" ./script1.sh "$PortStart"
```

with

```
./script1.sh "$PortStart"
```

Then get rid of all the lock commands. You should end up running the three script in order.